# Instagram API - Is it possible to search for a users hashtag posts

Tags: api, instagram

Is it possible to search all posts with a specific hashtag by a certain user?

I am new to development and I am trying out Instagram's API if I can search such combination.

Comment: I am not really sure why you get downvote. It's actually quite good question

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but not using only a single request to Instagram's API. There are two solutions:

1. Search for posts by given hashtag's name using `GET /tags/{tag-name}/media/recent` request and then manually check every post if its user is the user you want.
2. Search for posts by specific user using `GET /users/{user-id}/media/recent` request and then manually check every post if its tags array contains the specific hashtag you want.

I would recommend to choose the solution in which you can expect less results (posts) to filter. In most cases it means the second one, because there is more posts on Instagram with a specific hashtag than an average user share on its Instagram's accout.

You can test Instagram's API requests with Instagram's API Console: http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/

Comment: any new solutions on this? i am looking for an answer